# "Segmentation fault" in multithreading with priority by c in linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, thread-priority

I am trying to develop a program which has multithreading with priority by c in linux. So my code is below. When i run my program, i meet "Segmentation fault".I don't know what happend. Please help me.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *max(void *);
void *avg(void *);
void *min(void *);

int tmp[5];
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_t thread3;
    pthread_setschedprio(thread1,2);
    int i, j;
    printf("Input number: \n");
    for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
        printf("tmp[%d]: ",j);
        scanf("%d: ",&tmp[j]);
    }
    if ((i=pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, max, tmp)) != 0) {
        printf("thread creation failed. %d\n", i);
    }

    if ((i=pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, avg, tmp)) != 0) {
        printf("thread creation failed. %d\n", i);
    }
    if ((i=pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, min, tmp)) != 0) {
        printf("thread creation failed. %d\n", i);
    }

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);
    printf("Exiting main\n");
    return 0;
}
void *max(void *arg){
    int i;
    int *arr = (int *)arg;
    int max = arr[0];
    for(i=1;i<5;i++){
        if(max<arr[i]){
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Max of array is: %d\n", max);
    sleep(1);
    return NULL;
}

void *avg(void *arg){
    int i;
    int *arr = (int *)arg;
    int sum =0;
    float avg;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    avg = sum/5.0;
    printf("Average of array is: %f\n",avg);
    sleep(1);
    return NULL;
}

void *min(void *arg){
    int i;
    int *arr = (int *)arg;
    int min = arr[0];
    for(i=1;i<5;i++){
        if(min>arr[i]){
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Min of array is: %d\n", min);
    sleep(1);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Hi.  so I built your code and ran it, looked like this: http://pastebin.com/vtARWMuE - no segmentation fault.  Maybe race condition.  ps: gcc command `gcc -lpthread -o t t.c` may help some to reproduce.

Comment: Just for fun ran it in a loop with ruby handing in random input ( and removed the sleeps ) and I can't get this sucker to crash for the life of me. `while ruby -e '5.times { x =  rand(9999999); $stderr.puts x; puts x }' | ./t ; do true; done`

Comment: Are you allowed to call `pthread_setschedprio` before creating the thread?  Is `printf` thread safe?

Comment: 1. Compile with debug symbols on and optimizations off: `-g -O0` 2. `$ gdb a.out` 3. `> run` 4. crash 5. `> backtrace`

Comment: @someuser what is the mutex supposed to protect? The threads only read from the array, no thread does any shared writes, so there is no race condition. This code is lock-free.

Comment: It's possible that your particular `printf` is not thread safe. I've gotten segfaults from clang's `cout` when about 8 or more threads print at the same time. It's worth commenting out the printfs to see if it cures it. You could also put different sleep counts, or have the main thread do prints. This could be why no-one else can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `pthread_setschedprio(thread1,2);` when `thread1` hasn't been initialized to a valid value.  You can set the priority for a thread only after the thread has been created.

To be clear, you should indicate whether or not commenting out the call to `pthread_setschedprio(thread1,2)` enables the program to run without crashing.  (Also - do you really want the colon in the `scanf()` format string?)

Answer (score -1):

here:

```
scanf("%d: ",&tmp[j]);
```

may be this line creating problems, observe : after `%d`, I don't think so it is the place.

May be this is the reason.